# Returning static array inaccessible dynamic type

Tags: solidity, arrays

In the first contract I have:

```
function getArray() external view returns(uint[] memory result) {
    uint counter = 0;
    result = new uint[](3);
    for (uint i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        result[counter] = i;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

In the second contract I have somewhere:

```
uint[] r = contractA.getArray();
```

I receive

```
TypeError: Type inaccessible dynamic type is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256[] storage pointer.
```

Comment: You can now do the above without errors. This was added in Solidity version 0.4.22

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [Github Issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/164). It seems the EVM can't handle dynamic return types from external functions yet. So as it is this just isn't possible.

However, since you're actually returning a static array of size 3, you can alter the code like this, although you're limited to an array of a specified size:

```
function getArray() external view returns(uint[3] memory result) {
    uint counter = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        result[counter] = i;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And in the separate contract do:

```
uint[3] memory r = contractA.getArray();
```

Edit: Since the Byzantium hardfork the EVM is capable of handling dynamic return types from external functions. However, it doesn't seem to be implemented in Solidity yet. This open [Github Issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3270) will hopefully enable it. We may be able to experiment with it using `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;` before it's released, although I don't think we can yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the program as follows:

```
function getArray() external view returns(uint[] memory result) {
    uint[] result;
    for (uint i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        result.push(i);
}
```